# Stateless services in Ruby application and creating new instance every time

Tags: ruby, service

I'm coming from Java world where stateless-service-based systems are popular.
In Ruby world it is not so popular and I can't find any answer, how to do that.

Say I need CRUD service to store Orders. It is pure stateless, no instance variables, just methods like `create`, `read`, etc. I wonder if I should create new instance of it every time I want to use it? In java with Spring or Guice you have one instance that may be used concurrently.

I can think of the following ways to implement that

1) regular class, and call `OrderRepository.new` every time

```
  class OrderRepository
    def create(order)
       ..
    end
  end
```

2) class methods and call `OrderRepository.create` (doesn't sound good)

```
  class OrderRepository
    def self.create(order)
       ..
    end
  end
```

3) module instead of class

Which one is preferable in such case?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would use class level methods. Opinions may vary, but I don't see any point in instantiating an instance of something if you don't actually need one. I also don't see any point in adding a gem like singleton or adding a framework if you don't need one, or if one is not appropriate to your goals.

Answer (score -2):

there are a lot of patterns in java land that do not map to a dynamic language like ruby. eventhough there is a whole book about design-patterns in ruby ([http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Ruby-Russ-Olsen/dp/0321490452](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452)) most of them are useless.

when you are talking about CRUD, you are probably talking about an HTTP speaking API that you can use to manage some database entities.

in ruby land you probably use rails to do such stuff as it has great support for building RESTfull applications and JSON apis.

so please, PLEASE, do not ever create a DAO or a Repository class in ruby. there is just no need for that (most of the times).

Comment: Ok, let's leave simple CRUD aside and suppose I need to periodically fetch some `Document` objects from MongoDB and put them into queue to let other system process them one by one. In Java I'd create `Scheduler` to run periodically and it'd use `DocumentsRepository` to fetch data from MongoDB and `DocumentsToQueueSender` to put fetched docs to queue. Those all would be stateless services. How would you implement stuff above in Ruby?

Comment: In ruby land you might use Rails, but rails is very heavyweight and not everybody likes the way it does things--some people might not want to be part of the next Rails apocalypse(http://labs.headshift.com/2012/03/07/on-rails-mass-assignment-github-and-the-apocalypse/). There's nothing wrong with building your own DAL, I've been on teams that did so--it was complex but we got exactly what we wanted and nothing we didn't.

Comment: it would be helpful if you change your question related to the example that you just gave, so that people can actually help you. from what you write i don't think that i can help you.